# retrieve two matches from a line by reference 2 values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have a file with 3 main names in a column.

```
Names
------
George
John
Victor
```

below the names at column `A` I have 3 categories

```
food
drink
super
```

at the right of the file i have data `1 + 2 + 3`

note that the 3 categories are not in the same order all the time.

What is the best way to retrieve data point 3 for each name with category drink and food only in another cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok, now I understand the full extent of your problem, the below code will actually do what you require. In future, try and explain the limits of variables that you need to process, and the limits or constraints that you need to work to.

Noting your pasted copy of your workbook, the following should work:

```
Sub Get_Third_Value()
    Dim Totals() As Variant, Names() As String, Cats() As String
    Dim X As Integer, Cur_Pers As Integer, Y As Integer, Z As Integer, No_Cats As Integer, No_Ppl As Integer, Last_Row As Integer
    Dim Tmp_Val As String
    ReDim Totals(1 To 7, 1 To 1) As Variant
    ReDim Names(1 To 1) As String
    ReDim Cats(1 To 1) As String
    Dim Data As Variant
    Do
        'This lets the user determine which data column they wish to total.
        Data = -1
        Data = InputBox("Please state which Data Value you wish to total:", "Total which Data:", "3")
        If IsNumeric(Data) = False Then Data = -1
    Loop Until Data > 0 And Data < 4
    For X = 2 To 10000
        'This for loop is used to generate a list of People's Names and the Categories of data (E.G. Food, Drink, Super, etc).
        'There is an assumption that there will only be a maximum of 7 Categories.
        If Range("A" & X).Value = "" Then
                'This ensures that at the end of the list of data the process ends.
                Last_Row = X - 1
                Exit For
        End If
        Tmp_Val = LCase(Range("A" & X).Value)
        If No_Cats <> 0 Then
                For Y = 1 To No_Cats
                    If Tmp_Val = Cats(Y) Then GoTo Already_Added 'This checks the array of Categories and skips the remainder if this already exists in that array.
                Next Y
        End If
        For Y = (X + 1) To 10000
            If Range("A" & Y).Value = "" Then GoTo Add_Name 'If the value is not repeated in the list, it must be someone's name.
            If Tmp_Val = LCase(Range("A" & Y).Value) Then
                    'If the value is repeated in the list in Column A, it must be a Category of data.
                    If No_Cats = 0 Then
                            'When no Categories have been added to the array of Categories, then the first is just added.
                            No_Cats = 1
                            ReDim Preserve Cats(1 To No_Cats) As String
                            Cats(No_Cats) = Tmp_Val
                        Else
                            'If the Category wasn't already found in the array of Categories, then this adds it.
                            No_Cats = No_Cats + 1
                            ReDim Preserve Cats(1 To No_Cats) As String
                            Cats(No_Cats) = Tmp_Val
Dont_Add_Cat:
                    End If
                    'Once the category has been added, then you don't need to keep checking the list.
                    GoTo Already_Added
            End If
        Next Y
Add_Name:
        No_Ppl = No_Ppl + 1
        ReDim Preserve Names(1 To No_Ppl) As String
        ReDim Preserve Totals(1 To 7, 1 To No_Ppl) As Variant
        Names(No_Ppl) = Tmp_Val
Already_Added:
    Next X
    For X = 2 To Last_Row
        For Y = 1 To No_Ppl
            'This for loop checks the current row against the list of names.
            If LCase(Range("A" & X).Value) = Names(Y) Then
                    Cur_Pers = Y
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next Y
        For Y = 1 To No_Cats
            'This for loop checks the current row against the array of Categories and increments the total as required.
            If LCase(Range("A" & X).Value) = Cats(Y) Then
                    Totals(Y, Cur_Pers) = Totals(Y, Cur_Pers) + CInt(Range(Cells(X, Data + 1).Address).Value)
                    Exit For
            End If
        Next Y
    Next X
    With Range(Cells(Last_Row + 2, 3).Address & ":" & Cells(Last_Row + 2, 2 + No_Cats).Address)
        .Merge
        .Value = "Data " & Data
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    For X = 1 To No_Ppl
        Range("B" & X + (Last_Row + 4)).Value = UCase(Left(Names(X), 1)) & Right(Names(X), Len(Names(X)) - 1)
    Next X
    For Y = 1 To No_Cats
        Range(Cells(Last_Row + 3, 2 + Y).Address).Value = "Sum of " & Cats(Y)
        Range(Cells(Last_Row + 4, 2 + Y).Address).Value = Cats(Y)
        For X = 1 To No_Ppl
            Range(Cells(Last_Row + 4 + X, 2 + Y).Address).Value = Totals(Y, X)
        Next X
    Next Y
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code but it looks is not running. Just to be clear and apologies if was not very clear. I want under George and food to return number 26 from data 3. Same way i want under Victor and drink to return data3 number 36. Always taking into account that the order of food drink and super might be different and also that might be the case i have sometimes only food or only drink under A collumn.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code is there a way automatically to pick up newly added items below the names? And also if I have new names I have to update the mapping right?

Comment: @Kostas are you wanting their to be more than just the three people? Or are you saying that you may wish to total the food and super categories instead? You could easily change the above code to automatically total all categories for all people, but there would need to be some assumptions (Like there couldn’t be the same name twice, and when a category was added all members would have that category under their name)

Comment: Hi Sercho , apologies was not very clear i am new here so trying my best.  I receive every week a list with names and categories below each name ( food , drink etc). Each week a new name might be added at the list or a name might be removed.Can we automatically pick up the new names in and names out? What i am trying to achieve really is automatically putting the names present at the list in one new column or new tab &  next to the column name  having data point 2 & 3 for food and drink

Comment: So will there only ever be the same three categories (Food, Drink, Super)? Or will these change as well?

Comment: They might also change from 3 to 7 different variables including Food Drink and Super

Comment: Ok, will those variables always exist below each person (no matter the order)?

Comment: they do exist but each name might have one week 5 variables below and next week 3. is not 100% sure that each time you will have 3 certain variables below all the time

Comment: Ok. I think I’ve got the idea of what you actually need now. But I’m out atm, when I get back home I will put together an update on my code above to solve the full problem.

Comment: This is brilliant . Thank you very much for the help. Is it possible please to ask a last question? is there any way to extract both line 2 + 3 without to have to choose at the beginning the columns and get the new values with names and columns ( 2+3)  in a new tab starting at the top A1 cell ?

Comment: @Kostas I would suggest you post that as a new question... after having a go at achieving it yourself.

Comment: Hi sercho, again thank you for the help and tried the code myself but I realized that your code does not allow decimals .then if you try to change the code has to be rebuild from the scratch.is there an easy way to allow the final values to have several decimals at the end of each number ?

Comment: @Kostas just change Cint to Cdbl, but you should really post those follow ups as a new question.